# IntegrityError at /likes/9/ FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I wanted to create "Like button" features, however, it only works while 0 < post_id < 7, and if post_id increases over 8, Django pops error like this:

> IntegrityError at /likes/8/ FOREIGN KEY constraint failed During
>   handling of the above exception (Like matching query does not exist.),
>   another exception occurred:
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py"
>   in _commit
>     239.                 return self.connection.commit()
>
> The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct
>   cause of the following exception:
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/mingselene/Documents/GitHub/network/feedback/views.py" in
>   likes
>     42.     new_like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, post_id=post_id)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py"
>   in manager_method
>     82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in get_or_create
>     488.             return self._create_object_from_params(lookup, params)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in _create_object_from_params
>     530.             raise e
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in _create_object_from_params
>     522.                 obj = self.create(**params)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py"
>   in **exit**
>     212.                         connection.commit()
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py"
>   in commit
>     261.         self._commit()
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py"
>   in _commit
>     239.                 return self.connection.commit()
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py"
>   in **exit**
>     89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py"
>   in _commit
>     239.                 return self.connection.commit()
>
> Exception Type: IntegrityError at /likes/8/ Exception Value: FOREIGN
>   KEY constraint failed

I cannot understand why it occurs, and stackoverflow posts were not effective.

```
views.py:
def likes(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id = post_id)
    new_like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, post_id=post_id)
    if not created:
        post.numOfLike -= 1
        like = Like.objects.get(user=request.user, post_id=post_id)
        like.delete()
        created = True
    else:
        post.numOfLike += 1
    post.save(update_fields=['numOfLike'])
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

models.py:
    class Like(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey('feedback.Subject', default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
        isUserLiked = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)"
```

Comment: Do you have posts with id > 8 in your database?

Comment: I don’t have that code on my database, but it occurs after I resetted database, too.

Comment: I think you somehow try to create like on a post that does not exist. If you resetted database you should have errors on POST `/likes/1` unless you don't have fixtures. Also I don't understand what is `feedback.Subject` on your model. Can you please share this additional code too?

Comment: Why have you given default value in your post and user fields (not a good practice to set default like this, can cause issues in future. ) ? Also, is post referring to correct foreign key `feedback.Subject` ?

Comment: I found error - I connected another model to here(feedback.Subject), not I wanted to connect. Sorry for making question like this. Thanks for helping me finding error!

Comment: @SeleneLee totally unrelated but you REALLY want to make sure your view only accepts POST requests - GET requests MUST be idempotent (they must NOT change the server's state).  Also, the `Like.objects.get(user=request.user, post_id=post_id)` in the if branch is useless - you already have this exact same record in `new_like` if `created` is false.